# Is this disaccharide sucrose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, lewis-structure

I want to know if the structure I drew is sucrose or an enantiomer of it.

**The One I Made:**
[image: The one I made]

---

**The one on internet:**
[image: The one on internet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the same molecules - the fructose part has just been rotated about the glycosidic bond (the oxygen between the two).

[Enantiomers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enantiomer) are molecules that have the same formula, but are non-superimposable - there have to be differences in [chirality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry)). If you can superimpose the structures by rotating about a bond or by rotating the molecule, it is not an enantiomer.

Comment: Aha! you mean rotating the fructose ring on a horizontal axis by $180^o$, I didn't notice that...

Comment: I agree that the drawn structure is sucrose